# Highlight Peak Point Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

In Excel 2010, I want to automatically highlight the peak point on this graph (the 3rd one from left to right), so it'll become red.

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to Superuser. What have you tried and/or researched on your own?

Comment: Do you want to highlight the overall maximum or any local peak?

Comment: It's possible to do this with a scatter chart using a named array formula and a trick with the y-axis minimum. I don't have time to write up a proper answer, but see  [this link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/48805010/chartmaxpoint.xlsx) for an example sheet.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to create a second column of data with formulas that only put a value in the cell with the maximum value, then add that column to the data and format it differently so it stands out.

This [link](http://chandoo.org/wp/2010/11/11/highlight-data-points-scatter-line-charts/) has more information on how to do this. (From www.chandoo.org post titled "Highlighting Data Points in Scatter and Line Charts")

Here are the highlights:

- Create a new column next to your data

Let's assume you have data in columns A and B with headers in row 1. In cell C2 enter the formula:

```
=if(B2=max(B:B),B2,NA())
```

Then copy it down for all your data

- Add the data in column C to your chart

Title it "Max"

- Format the new Data Series

Select a bigger marker size and the color you want the marker to be.

Comment: That has problems associated with it. You need to create a new series (IIRC you can't hide it afterwards) and you need to manually format the series' value. At any rate, can you please post the relevant parts of the method, as to avoid *link rot*?

Comment: It is possible to hide the extra column of data with a change to the chart properties. Also, once the formulas are entered there is should be no other interaction needed.